# How to open Youtube URL with Safari, not Youtube app

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I want to open a Youtube URL using Safari, but it keeps presenting it with the Youtube app.

I am using this code to open URL's in an Action Extension:

```
func open(_ url: URL) {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self as UIResponder
    let selector = #selector(openURL(_:))
    while responder != nil {
        if responder!.responds(to: selector) && responder != self {
            responder!.perform(selector, with: url)
            return
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
}
```

And the URL looks like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/sd0BOnN6aNY/?controls=1&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.khanacademy.org&iv_load_policy=3&html5=1&autoplay=1&fs=1&rel=0&hl=en&cc_lang_pref=en&cc_load_policy=1&start=20
```

Comment: I see that some are suggesting adding "youtube://" in front of link to open in YouTube app. Have you tried adding "safari://" instead? :)

Comment: Yes and it did not work. But I find it funny!

Comment: have you tried opening it in Safari View controller..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this

```
let url = URL(string : "https://www.youtube.com/embed/sd0BOnN6aNY/?controls=1&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.khanacademy.org&iv_load_policy=3&html5=1&autoplay=1&fs=1&rel=0&hl=en&cc_lang_pref=en&cc_load_policy=1&start=20")!
```

Comment: This is the way I am sending the URL to my function. But it keeps opening it up with the Youtube app. I want it to open the URL in Safari.

Comment: Ok understand then you should use Webview. after your method is webView.loadRequest(url) this works only Safari but you need change URL to URLRequest